# Slice table into trunks with size of N?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to write a stored procedure

```
create proc GetTrunk @trunk int, @tableName sysname, @trunksize int = 5000
as
with    t as ( 
           select PK1, PK2, ntile(@trunksize) over ( order by PK1, PK2 ) t
           from     ABigTable -- Just put table name directly here for testing
 -- the table has a composite pk of pk1 and pk2
         )
select  pk1, pk2
from    t
where   t = @trunk;
```

Running `GetTrunk 3, 'tname', 5000` will return slice the table into the trunks of size of 5000 and get the 3rd trunk of primary keys of the trunk.

However, it's very slow for big table. Is it a better way to get a window of the table?

Comment: You might want to look at paging techniques. You would normally use something like  select top 5000 where PK>lastkey, using keys instead of an index for the trunk. That is very fast.

Comment: You might want to look at Paul White's articles on pagination: [Part 1](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/paging/69892/), [Part 2](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/paging/70120/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the [ORDER BY enhancements of OFFSET and FETCH](http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.in/2010/11/order-by-enhancements-in-sql-server.html). Something like this:

```
create proc GetTrunk @trunk int, @tableName sysname, @trunksize int = 5000
as

           select PK1, PK2
           from     ABigTable 
           order by PK1, PK2 OFFSET ((@trunk -1) * @trunksize)  ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT @trunksize ROWS ONLY
```

I think it will perform better than NTILE.

Comment: It's still very slow for very large tables. I just need to read forward only so I turned to use cursor.